# How to create a key value pairs of couchbase document using couchbase query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am writing couchbase query for my project and facing problem in 1 query. Below is the details of the problem.

I have a bucket name as "workflow" and I have few documents in it :-

```
{
     type = "task",
     status = "Completed",
     appId = "72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12",
     taskNo = 1
},
{
     type = "task",
     status = "Completed",
     appId = "72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12",
     taskNo = 2
},
{
     type = "task",
     status = "New",
     appId = "72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12",
     taskNo = 3
},
{
     type = "task",
     status = "New",
     appId = "72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12",
     taskNo = 4
},
{
     type = "task",
     status = "New",
     appId = "72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12",
     taskNo = 5
}
```

I have written a query :-

```
select status, count(*) from workflow where type="task" and appId="72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12" and status!="" group by status;
```

Result :-

```
[
   {
       "$1": 2,
       "status": "Completed"
   },
   {
       "$1": 3,
       "status": "New"
   }
]
```

Expected Result :-

```
[
    {
        "Completed": 2
    },
    {
        "New": 3
    }
]
```

Is there a way that we can get the expected result? Any leads will be really very helpful. I will be saved from running unnecessary for loop which will optimise my code during scaling. And any other alternative for the below statement?

```
status!=""
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select RAW {status:count(1)} 
from workflow 
where type="task" 
      and appId="72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12" 
      and status != "" 
group by status;
```

OR

```
SELECT RAW OBJECT v.status:v.cnt 
           FOR v IN (select status, count(1) AS cnt 
                     from workflow 
                     where type="task" 
                           and appId="72689c67-f5d1-474a-8802-77f332144b12" 
                           and status != "" 
                     group by status)
            END;
```

You can use status > "" AND status < []

Comment: Thank you @vsr, it gave me the result